# How to Deploying a Dockerized ( NestJS app ) to Cloud Service Provider like Amazon Web Services (AWS), Microsoft Azure, Google Cloud

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, deployment, nestjs

Here is a sample of my docker-compose.yml file

The app runs well all I am asking for is the steps to configure for production and deployment steps to any of the cloud service providers.

The docker-compose file contains my API service, Postgres Image, and pgAdmin for development

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  # Our NestJS Api
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./api
      # Only build development stage from Dockerfile
      target: development
    # Mount our host dir to the docker container
    # Mount api directory (./api) to (:) docker container (/kdb/src/app)
    # Reflect File changes from host to container
    volumes:
      - ./api:/kdb/src/app
      - /kdb/src/app/node_modules/
    # RUN in debug mode: npm run start:debug --> Also start your vscode debugger
    # Run in dev mode: npm run start:dev
    command: npm run start:dev
    depends_on: 
      - postgres
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://user:password@postgres:5432/db
      NODE_ENV: development
      JWT_SECRET: hard_to_guess_secret_123
      PORT: 3000
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 9229:9229
  
  # Postgresql
  # Our Postgres Database for NestJS to connect to
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.4
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: db
    ports:
      - 35000:5432

  # The Postgres Admin tool if we want to run some custom queries and so on against our Database
  postgres_admin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:4.28
    depends_on: 
      - postgres
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - 5050:80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the example of AWS.

#### Deploying the application on EC2 instance

1. You will need to create the EC2 instance and install the required dependencies like docker itself on the instance. Ensure that you are creating it with a public IP (assign a static IP if required) [Referral doc EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html)
2. Open the ports in security groups which need to be accessed externally. If you want the application to be accessible at port 443 using HTTPS, then we need to open port 443 for HTTPS protocol. [Security groups docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html)
3. Once everything is installed and the application is up and running, you should be able to access the application using Public IP and the port.

#### Assigning a route53 record to the instance for user friendly domain.

1. You should be the owner of the domain say `domain.com`.
2. Create a hosted zone in AWS with the nameservers set as per your domain name. Create a route 53 A, record pointing to the public IP address of the instance.
3. Now you will be able to access the same application with `http://domainname.com:443`

### How do we scale and go to the next level?

Make the Application stateless

1. The state of the application should be stored in external databases. If you have multiple instances of docker-compose running in multiple instances, they cannot communicate with each other and it's a mess. So what do we do?
2. We move the database to a managed service or a separate EC2 instance.
3. We create a DockerImage of our application and use a container orchestration framework like Kubernetes.
4. You can test the application locally as well by deploying on local-k8s. [Some-tasks-that-can-help](https://github.com/codeaprendiz/devops-essentials/tree/main/kubernetes)
5. You will need to choose an ingress. You can go with [Traefik](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/kubernetes-ingress), [Kong](https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/latest) or any other ingress depending on your requirement.
6. You will need to create a loadbalancer service type to expose the application externally. [Referral Docs - Traefik](https://traefik.io/blog/combining-ingress-controllers-and-external-load-balancers-with-kubernetes/)
7. You can create an Alias A record in your hosted zone and assign it to your load balancer. [Referral Docs - Route53 and ALB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html)
8. You can use AWS Certificate Manager for creating certificates for free. [ACM And ALB](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/associate-acm-certificate-alb-nlb)